# select datas from firsttable and order by field in secondtable in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. First table is `je_addchoice`, which contains fields like

- choiceid
- pollid
- choicename
- choicecreatorid

and the second table is `je_uservote` and the fields are

- userid
- pollid
- choiceid

What i want to do is,

Display the choice names based on the no of votes in the `je_uservote` table

```
$query = select * from je_addchoice where poll_id='$poll_id' //order by (count(choiceid)) from second table
```

//QUERY FOR DISPLAY CHOICENAMES BASED ON COUNT OF VOTES

How to write the above query

My question is how to access the no of counts in the jeuservote table and display the choicenames based on the result count. Actually the votes for the choicenames in the addchoice table count is stored in the jeuservote table. How can i access the vote count for the choice names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (
            SELECT count(*) 
            FROM je_uservote T2 
            WHERE T2.pollid=T1.pollID 
            AND T2.choiceid=T1.choiceID) AS votes
FROM je_addchoice T1
ORDER BY votes
```